# AngularJs' model in dynamic view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

Here is what i am trying to do.

In this app, user can click "Add" to add whatever category they want in this form, and i will save all of them, then output it. However, i could not figure out how to output them.

Here is a working example for the dynamic view:http://plnkr.co/edit/j5RGMi3RTPZ85XGvaa2D?p=preview

Here is the js file:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('ctrl',['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.templates = [];
$scope.addTemplate = function(){
    $scope.templates.push('category');
};
}]);
```

Here is the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

```
<p>Append Category via button click</p>
<button ng-click="addTemplate()">Add Category</button>
<div ng-repeat="template in templates">
<ng-include src="template"></ng-include></div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="category">
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="categoryTitle">Title</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input id="categoryTitle" name="categoryTitle" ng-model="category.title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input your category title" required>
      </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <!-- Begin textarea -->
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <textarea id = "nonresizable" class="form-control" ng-model="category.content" placeholder="Input your category content here" rows="5" required></textarea>
          <hr>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End textarea -->
</form>
```

```
 <p>The inputed Category</p>

 <label>Title</label>
 <div>{{category.title}}</div>
 <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <textarea>{{category.content}}</textarea> 
    <hr>
</div>
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: What does `note` have to do  `page`? What are the expected results of this? Then question says add category .... quite confusing

Comment: sorry for the bad naming....I modified the plunker, hope this makes sense. I just want to save all the data generated by this dynamic view.

Comment: Still not clear what the objective is or what expected results are

Comment: i want to get all the data that has inputted in the form. i modified the plunker again.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did more research and made it work! YAY!

Here is a live demo in plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/AQFlEV6FDEKRAsvBc0PE?p=preview.

```
$scope.addField = function() {
  $scope.data.fields.push({
  content: "test " + counter++
});
```

};

Basically I need to dynamic add the name for each category, everytime push the new category to the scope. Hope this makes sense.

Thanks again for all the answers!

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the content in $scope.templates after you add the a note/page?

If you want to change the content of every note in the template you can:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('ctrl',['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.templates = [];
$scope.addTemplate = function(){
    $scope.templates.push({
        content1 : "content1text",
        content2 : "content3text",
        content3 : "content3text"
});
};
```

Comment: but i won't be able to know about how many content i would have every time, as the user will add it dynamically. does it make sense?

Comment: you can add a watch on the `$scope.templates` variable:
`$scope.watch('templates',function(oldValue,newValue){
     //DO STUFF HERE
});`
So every time the variable change you can do what you want, more info in: [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Answer (score 0):

You can make somethinkg like that

just proposition

Templates.js

```
var tempsObj = {} | tempsObj;
tempsObj.templates = function(){
 var template = [];
 template ["templates1"] = "folder1/";
 template ["templates2"] = "folder1/";
 return template;
}


tempsObj.selectedTemp = "templates1";
```

Module.js

```
var app = angular.module("plunker",['ngRoute']);

home.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){

$routeProvider

    .when('/',{

        templateUrl : tempsObj.templates[tempsObj.selectedTemp]+'plunker.html',
        controller : 'plunkerController'
    })
    .when('/404',{
        templateUrl : tempsObj.templates[tempsObj.selectedTemp]+'404.html',
        controller : '404Controller'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/404'
    });



 });
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but the user can add infinite template here, so i don't really understand the template ["templates1"] = "folder1/"; part....please clarify?